# Как начать тестировать плагин для Redmin`а?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, rspec

Добавляю функционал в плагин для redmin`а. 
Не могу понять как собственно запустить общие тесты.

```
rake test
```

или вообще любая задача с тестами из списка `rake -T` выдают кучу ошибок и фейлов.

```
bundle exec rspec
0 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: Попробуйте `rails -T test:plugins`